# Run demo of JBullet in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jbullet

Has anyone successfully run demo of JBullet in IntelliJ?
When I run the demo using the ant build script, i found a mistake like this :

> C:\Users\halin_000\ProgrammingProjects\Java\CS351L\JBullet\build.xml:77:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: first parameter of Stack.alloc(Class)
>   must be constant (in class
>   com.bulletphysics.collision.dispatch.ConvexConcaveCollisionAlgorithm,
>   method processCollision)

How do you solve the problem?

Comment: Welp, I have the same problem. Did you resolve it?

Comment: @Zackkenyon I did not. I used [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) instead. It integrates JBullet.

Comment: yeah, but there's an extension to Jbullet that I wanted

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today. I used to be able to build jbullet a few years ago and I had the source put under version control back then.

It turns out building with a Java 7 compiler (from jdk1.7.0_79) works fine while building with a Java 8 compiler (from jdk1.8.0_101) fails with the message the OP reported.

I suppose a more definitive solution would be to update the vecmath library to satisfy the higher standards of a Java 8 compiler, but in the meantime I have reverted my toolchain to a state where I can get going.

**Update 2016-10-08 22h30 EDT**

Not satisfied of reverting my toolchain to Java7, I have dwelved a bit deeper into this issue and traced it to JStackAlloc, not vecmath as I previously thought.

It would seem compiling with Java8 adds more instruction nodes to the bytecode where there was none before. Specifically, *LineNumberNode* and *LabelNode* are being added between *LdcInsnNode* and *MethodInsnNode*.

JStackAlloc is looking for the later two but is not expecting to find the extra two nodes. It is easy to fix the library to skip these extra nodes and carry its job despite their presence.

Starting from a [maven'ized build of jbullet](https://github.com/jbullet-maven/jbullet), here is the diff required to [make it work again](https://github.com/gsimard/jbullet/commit/5ace1d64f07dc91e92a6dacb82d322540423a77e).

Note that the Javadoc build of this release seems to be broken. It can be disabled by commenting out the jar goal of the *maven-javadoc-plugin* in the *pom.xml* config file.